# Unable to set CEMarker's collisionPriority

Tags: ios, citymaps

I'm trying to "mimic" the BusinessLayer functionality by creating a CEMarkerGroup for my own markers, then setting the following:

```
CEMarkerGroup *myGroup = [self.mapView markerGroupWithName:@"myMarkers"];
[myGroup setShouldTestForCollisions:YES];
```

And then, according to the Citymaps' current [documentation](http://developer.citymaps.com/markers#marker-groups), I try to set individual collisionPriority values to each like this:

```
[marker setCollisionPriority:25.0f];   //<-- ERROR!!, or
marker.collisionPriority = 25.0f;      //<-- same ERROR
[myGroup addMarker:marker];
```

Error is: `No visible @interface for 'CEMarker' declares the selector 'setCollisionPriority:'`

As my goal is to approximate Citymaps' very slick behavior of avoiding marker overlaps, does anyone know of a workaround for this issue, or perhaps another approach altogether?  Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer at Citymaps. Thank you for your interest in our SDK!

Our documentation got a bit ahead of itself. Turns out, we never exposed the collisionPriority property. I've given myself a ticket to do so, and will let you know immediately when a new build is out containing this change.